# Calculate time difference in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT empno , date_created , 
min(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
max(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
FROM biometrics
WHERE empno = 3
GROUP BY empno , date_created
```

In this syntax it only determines the first in and last out of the employee but
I would like to ask how i can calculate the time difference or the total time of his/her between the first IN and last Out of the employee.

For example employee' first in is 9:00:00 am and last out is 16:00:00 in the afternoon. How can I compute the total hours work of this employee?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
select 
  empno, 
  date_created, 
  time_in, 
  time_out, 
  time_format(timediff(time_out, time_in), '%H:%i') as total_time 
from 
(
  SELECT empno, date_created, 
    min(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN time_created END) time_in,
    max(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN time_created END) time_out
  FROM biometrics
  WHERE empno = 3 
  GROUP BY empno, date_created
) t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

By this you can find the difference in hours between firstin and lastout

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, firstin(datetime), lastout(datetime)) FROM table_name
```